# Does there exist a group homomorphism $f:\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}/12\Bbb{Z} $ with $f(\bar 1)=\bar 3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Does there exist a group homomorphism

$f:\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}/12\Bbb{Z} $

$f(\bar 1)=\bar 3$

So what i have so far is
$f(\bar 0)=0$
$f(\bar 1)=3$
$f(\bar 2)=6$
$f(\bar 3)=9$

so $|Img(f)|=4$

but i dont know how to continue, can i please get some tips. Maybe first isomorphism theorem helps, or is there a shorter way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f(1)=3$.
Note that $0=6$ in $\Bbb{Z}_6$.
Hence $f(0)=f(6)$.
Since $f$ is a homomorphism, $f(0)=0$.
Also, $f(6)=6f(1)=6\cdot3=18$.
Hence we get $0=18$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: ok i understood this, how did you come up with this though, it doesnt seem so obvious? did you experiment ?

Comment: There is one property that $f:\Bbb{Z}_n\rightarrow \Bbb{Z}_m$ iff $\frac{m}{(m,n)}$ divides $f(1)$. @asddf

Comment: and also one last question : why is $f(6)= 6f(1)$

Comment: is it because $f(6)=f(1+1+1+1+1+1)$ ?

Comment: @asddf Yes. Since $f$ is homomorphism, $f(kx)=kf(x)$ for any integer $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you stop at $f(3) = 9$? What happens next, and is that allowed?

What I mean is, $f(4) = 12 = 0$, and $f(5) = 3$, and $f(0) = f(6) = 6$, and this is a problem!

In general, if $o(x) = \min\{ n > 0 : nx = 0\}$ is the order of $x$ (the group being written additively) and if $f$ is a group homomorphism, then $o(f(x))$ divides $o(x)$. In particular, $f(1)$ cannot equal $3$ because the order of $3$ in $\mathbf{Z}/12$ is $4$ whereas the order of $1$ in $\mathbf{Z}/6$ is $6$, and $4$ does not divide $6$.

Comment: thank you, could you link a proof of the last part ?

Comment: Here's a general fact: if $n = o(x)$ and $mx = 0$, then $n$ divides $m$, because if we write $m = nq + r$ with $0 \le r < n$ (quotient and remainder) then $0 = mx = (nq + r)x = q(nx) + rx = rx$ which means $r = 0$ (because $n$ is the *least positive* annihilator of $x$, and $r < n$). Now, since $nx = 0$ we have $nf(x) = f(nx) = f(0) = 0$ so that $o(f(x))$ divides $n = o(x)$.

Comment: thank you for helpin me :))

Answer (score 0):

$f([1])=[3]$ ;$\Bbb Z_6=\langle [1]\rangle \implies f[x]=f(x.[1])=x.f([1])=[3x]$

Now it remains to check whether $f([x+y])=[3(x+y)]=[3x]+[3y]=f([x])+f([y])$

Comment: why should the function be 3x ?

Comment: Since $f([1])=[3]\implies f(x)=f(x.[1])=xf([1])=[3x]$ @asddf

Comment: So $0$=$6$ in $Z_6$ yet $f(0)=0\not=6= f(6)$ in $Z_{12}$?